# How Can I make background images show up that are being blocked by Cross-Origin Read Blocking?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, cross-domain

I'm currently working on a React project and want to set the background image of individual items dynamically. I'm using inline styles within a React Component:

```
<div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.book.previewLink})` }}></div>
```

This is rendered as:

```
<div class="book-cover" style="width: 128px; height: 193px; background-image: url("http://books.google.com/books?id=sJf1vQAACAAJ&amp;dq=redux+react&amp;hl=&amp;cd=6&amp;source=gbs_api");"></div>
```

But in the browser (Chrome), these images won't show up at all, and in the console I find this message:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://books.google.com/books?id=jAUODAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=king&hl=&cd=8&source=gbs_api with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

My question is: how I can get around this, i.e. display background images sourced from URLs to anyone loading the site?

Comment: Your preview link just isn't right. try "https://books.google.de/books/content?id=sJf1vQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&imgtk=AFLRE71EG6zrFacr-IuuP-UGfXGvil3gpYLaVAeNTyg9M6j3mNR-LYs1tSkoNMYAgP46PDhDICrOLohmFKQFRgPtOvPbeLYXsPBBicBxJTYM8Ey7v3_SIm902Qh_UEvfHBE8aqeoNvoT" as your source for the image. You are currently trying to fetch a webpage with your request and not an image. Google doesn't allow that.

Comment: Thanks! The console.log message threw me, but with the correct link the problem disappears, as you say.